# 12.04 lts stuck on "preparing to install"

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install 12.04 lts from dvd and am stuck on the "preparing to install" screen which will not allow me to continue.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue, found a lot of stuff about partitions / etc... followed the instructions in the other answer to live boot / format / etc... It was still hanging while installing 12.04 at the same "preparing to install". I tried installing 14.04 this morning, and it worked perfectly. YMMV

Comment: @Kem What other answer?

Comment: The answer by Varun Das below, but note that what I said was that it didn't work either with 12.04 -- But when I tried 14.04 -- I didn't have to do anything special, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem would be caused by an **untidy partition**. So you want to format the drive you are longing to use for the installation.
For that ,
 **Step 1 :**  Live boot the OS from the dvd.
**Step 2 :** Open the Disk Manager and format the drive with the **Ext4** FileSystem.

Reinstall Ubuntu and you are done.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked for me, except I used GParted to put on an MS-DOS partition table without creating any partitions.

Answer (score 0):

i also experienced same issue when i was installing lubuntu on my mac . I made the usb with program called live usb. I booted to usb chose try lubuntu, run the installer opened terminal and deleted all partition using gparted or you can try make one ex4 before going to problematic step. Hope this helps