# Lubuntu hangs on "Preparing to install Lubuntu"

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, lubuntu

To give some background details, my computer runs 64-bit, I'm installing Lubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. I can sucessfully boot into Lubuntu's CD, and I reach the requirements to install Lubuntu, and I backed everything up. So, glad that I reach all of the requirements, I install Lubuntu. I reach the first screen about choosing the language perfectly, and continued.

Now I'm onto the second screen, telling me about the requirements of Lubuntu and some optional stuff that I can download during installation. I decided to install the optional software, and pressed next. However, when I pressed next, it freezes up and the only button I can press is exit.

So I try again the next day, and the same results. I did a bit of researching and found that [Ubuntu people have similar issues](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074949&s=c6df6e9623026303dccd00070ef5299c&p=12419908#post12419908). So, following what that guy said on the other forum, I tried burning the Alternative ISO onto disk and booting it up.

Well, I tried to do a lot of things. Here's a list:

1. [Alternative ISO](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074949&s=c6df6e9623026303dccd00070ef5299c&p=12419908#post12419908)
2. I couldn't [tidy up the partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387683/12-04-lts-stuck-on-preparing-to-install) because I planned to dualboot
3. I can't remake the swap partitions because I had none
4. On the next installation, I didn't install the optional software
5. Don't unmount the partition /dev/sda

I did some combinations of that, such as Alternative ISO and no optional software, and still no luck.